Access list for Assumed Role
I'm authentication to AWS with temporary security credentials from AWS Identity and Access Management Roles Anywhere.
Here's my identify:
$ aws sts get-caller-identity --profile myprofile
{               
    "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/MGMT-AWSAnywhere-Role/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
}

I was granted access to the S3 bucket
{
  "Sid": "AllowAccess"
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/MGMT-AWSAnywhere-Role/YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
  },
  "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:List*"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
  ]
}

but I've failed to access it:
$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket --profile myprofile

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Is it because Access list contanis wrong Principal/AWS value? What should be the right value or where do I get it?

I presume that is a Bucket Policy you are showing? Try changing the ARN to the ARN of the actual IAM Role (you can get it from the IAM console). It should look something like arn:aws:iam:: 123456789012:role/MGMT-AWSAnywhere-Role

I think you can use this policy generator provided by AWS.
https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html
